# How can we skip particular condition only but execute rest test in a test function?

Tags: pytest, skip

I want to skip test in pytest for particular condition but want to execute it for all other conditions inside test function.
for example my test is validating multiple conditions, but for one of them i want to skip.
if i am using pytest.skip ,its skipping all other tests as well.I don't want to skip entire test,but particular condition in my test.

for example in below code,i want to skip if parameter has bye,but i want to assert on all other conditions like 'hello' and 'hi' and other asserts as well.
say assert x,y and z

```
parameter = ['hello','bye',hi] 

#i don't want to parameterize it as i am using very long list and 
using it in multiple test in different packages

def test function():
#my test have multiple asserts
  assert x is true ,'x is not true'
  assert y is false, 'y is not false'
  for i in parameter: 
     assert is_present_in_json_file(i)
  assert z is true, z is not true'
```

Comment: A test is an atomic entity, you can't thus skip "parts" of a test. Either extract the code part in a separate test (you shouldn't put so many asserts in a single test anyway), or omit the execution of a line with an `if` condition as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the condition & skip the test if it matches

```
def test function():
    assert x is true ,'x is not true'
    assert y is false, 'y is not false'
    for i in parameter: 
        if i == 'bye':
            print(f"Skipping this parameter - {i} for reason")
            continue
        assert is_present_in_json_file(i)
        assert z is true, z is not true'
```

Comment: I tried this its skipping everything after it find 'bye' in parameter. Its neither checking 'hi' nor executing assert z is true, z is not true'.    It means pytest.skip will skip entire test as soon as it hit this condition.I don't want that.

Comment: Yes you are right. Can you just not assert for the matching condition?

Comment: Thats what i am trying to find? Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Did you look at the updated answer? That might be one way.